# Keeping images in the same spot, regardless of zooming in or out

Tags: html, css, image

I have a number of images on my site that I have positioned in various places. However, every time I zoom in or out on the page they move everywhere! Can someone assist me?

This is an example the kind of code I am using to position my images. Its the only code I have found personally that lets me set images anywhere I like. But still it moves when I zoom!

```html
    <IMG STYLE="position:absolute; TOP:2820px; LEFT:150px; WIDTH:100px; HEIGHT:100px" SRC="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/abstract-red-and-gold-paint-splatter-icons-culture/022426-abstract-red-and-gold-paint-splatter-icon-culture-heart-simple.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using **relative** positions. There lies the problem with using `px`'s to position things.

Try to position everything in a document relatively as much as you can. Very rarely should you position something with absolute measurements and if you are, it's probably the wrong way about it.

There's a number of ways to vertical align things - this way is by no means the best way. I doubt your question will last long before a duplicate is found. In any case, please see [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/defaye/yy22aw3k/).

```css
html,
body,
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent>.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <img class="child" src="https://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```

In future, you should show a more detailed example of your code. Also.. you should be writing your mark-up in lower case. Very few languages are going to have recommendations (if any) in upper case.

You should also not be writing your styles in-line where you can avoid it (nor in `<style>` tags - mine is just to group the example for your ease).